# Output Location for ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, personal-geodatabase

What I am trying to accomplish in ModelBuilder is netting road buffers and stream buffers from forest polygons.  I do not know python and I am relatively new to ModelBuilder. I attached the start of the model.  I had no problem running this model earlier, then I tried to create "Add Personal GDB" as a precondition, so that I could share this model with other people and they could use it with their data.

I have spent numerous hours searching and got close

1. Create Personal GDB and Designate its file location.

Then run a series of geoprocessing steps and I want to save the outputs to the same location to the original Personal GDB I created.

This one got me close. I am lost with the %output% stuff.
[Setting single output location for multiple files in ModelBuilder?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/18084)

This one also got me close.

[Output location in ModelBuilder?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/164651)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

So you create a  Personal GDB  as the first step in the model then want to use it as the output location for subsequent tools?

The way to do this is use inline variable substitution (search the help file for that). In your model the variable that holds this location  is the output of the create PGDB tool and you are calling it "Output Personal GDB", for arguments sake assume it holds `c:\temp\mypgdb.gdb`.  You would reference this path by the variable name which in your case would be `%Output Personal GDB%`

So for example in the buffer tool your output would be `%Output Personal GDB%\mybuffers`